# Opengl Shader Basic Computation

Tags: opengl, glsl

OS: Win7 VS 2012

Graphics Card: Inter HD 4000

I have no problem generating an image without any computation.
However, when I added p*vPosition for a prospective projection,
My window opened and closed immediately after I executed the program.
Could anyone point out what I have done wrong?
My vshsader.glsl code looks like this:

```
#version 150

in  vec4 vPosition;
in  vec4 vColor;
out vec4 color;

void main() 
{
    float d = -10.0;
    mat4 p = mat4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
                   0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
                   0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
                   0.0, 0.0, 1/d, 0.0);

  gl_Position = p*vPosition;
  color = vColor;
}
```

Comment: What the heck is a "Inter HD 4000"?

Comment: Was there any error printed to the console? It's unlikely your fragment program would cause the window to close immediately after execution. (It's possible that could happen if you didn't allocate enough memory to hold the string for the shader program and overwrote some other memory or something, but what you've described doesn't make much sense.) Can you explain in more detail and maybe include some application code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing commas at the end of each line of parameters to the mat4 constructor.

It should be:

```
mat4 p = mat4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, // <- end with comma
               0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, // <- end with comma
               0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, // <- end with comma
               0.0, 0.0, 1/d, 0.0);
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working now. How ever, my result does not show the right picture that I want. :( I see only white screen.

Comment: @PeterHwang Try reading the section on [this page](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-4-entering-the-third-dimension/) titled projection matrices and creating your projection matrix like that.